# quicksight cascading filters across datasets

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to have cascading filters in Quicksight that are tied to different datasets

I have a few dimension tables that I want to use to filter a fact table. The dimension tables are also related so that a user selection in filter A (tied to dimension table A), would limit the available options in filter B (tied to dimension table B).  I was hoping to just have a dataset per dimension table and then tie them together in quicksight but not seeing a way to do that. I can of course create a single "dimension table" in sql, which would still be better than scanning the fact table for filters but thought maybe there would be a cross-dataset relevant values functionality